# How to verify this checkbox is checked?

Tags: options, forms

Actually I want to include a file if the checkbox is checked

```
<?php
$checked = get_option('automatic') ? "checked='checked'" : "";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='automatic' $checked />";
?>

if(get_option('automatic') == 'checked')) ( require_once 'myfile.php'; )
```

This form is in a plugin option page

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='automatic' value='1' ".checked(1, get_option('automatic'))." />";

if (get_option('automatic') === '1') { require_once 'myfile.php'; }
?>
```

Comment: checked='checked' appear on the form and requre_once is not executed

Comment: Is the if statement getting cached? Replace require_once with `echo 'It works.';` to see.

Comment: bah it show It works

Comment: Thank. checked='checked' appear in the left side of the box after checked

Comment: @uanthanh - how about passing a third parameter `false`
Ex. - `checked(1, get_option('automatic'), false )`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
if( get_option('automatic') ) {

    // do something here

}
```

[Surely not](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)?

Comment: <?php
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='automatic' value='1' ".checked(1, get_option('automatic'))." />";

if (get_option('automatic') === '1') { function wp_automatically_shorcode($content) {
ob_start();
wp_automatically_functions();
$output_string=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $output_string;
}
add_shortcode('automatic', 'wp_automatically_shorcode');

function wp_automatically_functions() {
echo 'ACTIVATED';
}

?>

Comment: I want to write another function in my plugin. This is to be use only if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Something like this                                    if( get_option('automatic') //checked box is checked

    // write new function 

}

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p11.html).

An example:

```
$checked = get_option( 'automatic' ) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="automatic" value="automatic" ' . $checked . '/>';

// verify form submission (use nonces: wp_verify_nonce)

if ( isset( $_POST['automatic'] ) AND $_POST['automatic'] === 'automatic' )
{
    require_once( 'myfile.php' );
}
```

Comment: checkbox is fine but this is not executed require_once( 'myfile.php' );
}

Comment: My function are not executed if in is inside the conditon if ( isset( $_POST['automatic'] ) AND $_POST['automatic'] === 'automatic' )
{
    require_once( 'myfile.php' );
}

Comment: This is inside myfile.php `function wp_automaticlly_shorcode($content) {
ob_start();
wp_automaticlly_functions();
$output_string=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $output_string;
}
add_shortcode('automatic', 'wp_automaticlly_shorcode');

function wp_automaticlly_functions() {
echo 'ACTIVATED';
}
`

Answer (score 0):

I will not take more if your time. I just need to know why  my function inside the IF statement is not working. If I place it somewher without the IF staememt it work wonderfully

```
<?php

echo "<input type='checkbox' name='automatic' value='1' ".checked(1, get_option('automatic'))." />";

if (get_option('automatic') === '1') {
    function wp_automatically_shorcode($content) {
        ob_start();
        wp_automatically_functions();
        $output_string=ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output_string;
    }
    add_shortcode('automatic', 'wp_automatically_shorcode');

    function wp_automatically_functions() {
        echo 'ACTIVATED';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Its's funny. It works now. I had to call in with another add action function